# Ruby on rails Sum numeric result issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sum

I have a db in postgres, my table `Venta` has a column called "importe" (`numeric`). Using ruby on rails I execute this query in the console:

```
Venta.where(date:"2017-03-03").sum(:importe)
```

And the result is `0.762e3`

But the expected result is `762`.

How can i solve this problem? remember the column type is `numeric` and I cannot change it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use string formatting:

```
venta = Venta.where(date:"2017-03-03").sum(:importe)
= > 0.762e3

print_venta = '%d' % venta
=> "762"
```

The most common type characters are:

```
  Field  |  Format
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------
  d,i,u  | Convert argument as a decimal number.
  f      | Convert floating point argument as [-]ddd.dddddd,
         | where the precision specifies the number of digits after
         | the decimal point.
```

Source:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf